# How to use transformWith() to ignore failed futures?

Tags: scala, future

I need to process sequence of transformations into one transformation, in order to if I have some failed Future it should be just ignored(I am trying to do it without recover or recoverWith, but smth going wrong, code fails when meet any failure)

```
type Transformation[T] = T => Future[T]
//in - Seq(trans1, trans2, trans3)

in.reduce[Transformation[T]](
  (acc, el) =>
    acc.andThen[Future[T]](
      ft =>
        ft.flatMap(el)
          .transformWith[T](
            t =>
              t match {
                case Failure(exception) => ft //this line is the most suspicious for me
                case Success(value)     => Future.successful(value)
              }
          )
    )
)
```

Comment: The output of a transformation is the input to the next one?

Comment: The output of a transformation is the input to the next one?  - Yes, making the chain of transformations by composing them as I understand

Comment: I think I guess... it is because I do not process variant where acc initial fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `transformWith` doesn't seem to provide you the possibility to recover with the original input value from the previous step, because it has to work with a `Try`. What is it supposed to do if the `Try` turns out to be a failure? By that time, it does not have the original input to fall back to, it only has a `Throwable`, not a `T`. So, `transformWith` seems insufficient.

If the pipeline is just a few transformations long, you can try `foldLeft` with `fallbackTo`:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

type Transformation[T] = T => Future[T]
def chainTrafos[T](
  trafos: List[Transformation[T]],
  value: T
): Future[T] = {
  trafos.foldLeft(Future { value })(
    (f, t) => f.flatMap(x => t(x).fallbackTo(Future { x }))
  )
}


val ta: Transformation[Int] = x => Future { x * x }
val tb: Transformation[Int] = x => Future.failed(new Error("oops"))
val tc: Transformation[Int] = x => Future { x - 58 }

println(Await.result(chainTrafos(List(ta, tb, tc), 10), 10.seconds))
```

prints

```
42
```

Comment: Fine! Thanks! this work with failed initial future too!

Comment: Great use case of `fallbackTo`!